# Forms with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, task

i've been looking around and haven't been able to find out how to do this, i've been given a task to create a form in html that when the numbers 1-20 have been entered it will display (using php) Your grade is A, and then if the numbers 21-40 was entered it would display Your Grade is B so on... does anyone know how this would be possible to do.

Comment: Take a look how $_POST array is handled. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php and how IF statements work: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: Have a look at something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

Create a form like this

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="mark" id="mark" />
    <input type="submit"  />

</form>
```

In the action page using some **IF condition** you can do this

```
  <?php 
  $mark=$_POST['mark'];

  if($mark>0 && $mark<21)

   {

      echo "GRADE = A";

   }

    if($mark>20 && $mark<41)
   {

      echo "GRADE = B";

   }

     ?>
```

Try this method..... thx

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if(){}` for this.

put your condition in (...) and set your grade in {...}
for  Grade A

```
    $num is your value from form element 
    $num=$_REQUEST['your text box name'];
       if(1<=$num<=20){ $grade='A';}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch.. Some might call it abusing a switch.. but it's perfectly valid and offers good readability.

```
<?php

$input = 21; // replace with your form value

$output = '';

switch (true) {
    case $input <= 20:
        $output = "A";
        break;
    case $input <= 40:
        $output = "b";
        break;
    case $input <= 60:
        $output = "C";
        break;
    // etc..   
}
echo "Your Grade is $output" . PHP_EOL;
```